# How to warn user with a modalDialog that the session has expired?

Tags: jsf, session, primefaces, timeout, liferay

I want to warn user that his session has finished before redirect to the login form.

How could I show a modalDialog when session user has finished to block redirecting until he click the window?

Comment: please share what you tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start here: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf Just push the message and open a modal dialog. Have you tried this?